# QtSPIM: Returns various errors before proceeding when asking for variable and storing

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I will admit before I ask this question, this is probably my fourth day even looking at MIPS assembly. I am aware that MARS is a better program to use, but it is required that we use QtSpim. Just for now, I am trying to ask the user for a variable and then print it back after printing a string. I cannot say what error I receive, for the error changes depending on the integer value entered.

```
    .data

prompt: 
    .asciiz "Enter the number of elements in each vector: "
_enter:
    .asciiz "Enter "
_another:
    .asciiz "Enter another "
msg1:
    .asciiz " floating-point values one per line."
msg2:
    .asciiz " floating-point values."
newline:
    .asciiz "\n"
array1:
    .space 400
array2:
    .space 400
array3:
    .space 400
arrsize: 
    .word 1


    .text

main:
    # print message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    # input for num_elements
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, arrsize
    syscall

        # prompt for first x elements
    # print _enter
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, _enter          #_enter loaded in address $a0"
    syscall

    # print arrsize
    la $a0, arrsize
    lw $a0, arrsize
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    # print msg1
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msg1            #msg1 loaded in address $a0
    syscall

    # print newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

The strange part is I receive a seemingly random error before the code proceeds like normal. Sometimes I have to press enter several times, and other times the code returns some complex error before proceeding. I probably did something horribly wrong and I'll inevitably be told to go read a book (a good book would be helpful, to be honest), but what did I do horribly wrong in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, take up debugging, so you can find where it goes awry.  You have some erroneous looking syscalls, so maybe see if those are causing problems.

Comment: Yep, you were right. It was an unnecessary syscall between lines 35 and 37.